# Bullet indent not working within WORD 2019

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

2.28.2021
I have a list within a table and I am tired of clicking the INDENT button on the Toolbar.  Ctrl+Tab does not work; it only adds a large whitespace before beginning of text (the bullet icon or letter stays left-justified). I have the Proofing option set as described in other answers to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the proofing options would have to do with this.

I would recommend using the Define New MultiLevel List dialog for this. Here is MVP Shauna Kelly's [page on bullets](http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html) that gives the details. The indents (before and after) are set using that dialog.

Note, this has *nothing* to do with the bullets button on the Home tab!

Once you have this set up, you apply the bullets by applying the appropriate paragraph style, not by using the bullets button. You can [assign a keyboard shortcut](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330) to the relevant styles.